# How to make Ultisnips (vim) only trigger after a `>` character?

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I want to make a snippet which only triggers after a `>` symbol, that way if I'm inside a `(x<cursor>)`, and I hit tab it won't trigger, but if it's after an html tag like `<div>x<cursor>` it will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an insert-mode map:

```
inoremap > ><c-o>:echoe "inside tag"<cr>
inoremap < <<c-o>:echoe "outside tag"<cr>
```

replace `echoe` with the function or command you want to trigger inside html tags.

Edit:

```
inoremap > ><c-o>:silent! iunmap <c-v><tab<c-v>><cr>              
inoremap < <<c-o>:silent! imap <c-v><tab<c-v>> <Plug>SuperTabForward<cr>
```

If you have SuperTab plugin this should work. The first command disables tag completion when typing <kbd>></kbd>. The second command renables tab completion when typing <kbd><</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I want the tab completion letter to be `x` but I dont want it to expand if its preceeded by a `>` character. That way if I'm putting `(x)` in a argument it wont expand when I hit tab, but when I do `<div>x` it will

Comment: Hmm.. I appreciate the answer but I'd rather just do it right inside of the Ultisnips plugin (I gave you an upvote tho!). I have about 50 expansions that I want to use this for. It looks like I can do it with a 'trigger' regex but I can't find any examples of how to actually do that.

Comment: I guess the best way to taggle this problem in UltiSnips itself is with a context-sensitive snippet (see section 4.9 of the docs). A context can be any python expression that evaluates to true/false. So write an expression that  compares the number of opening < and closing > and let your snippet only trigger if they even out.